# Calculating values for I/O models

Tags: c, unix, memory, architecture

Just wondering how do I got about calculating a few values for Programmed I/O, DMA and Interrupt-driven I/O models.

If an application needs to output 1000 words from the internal memory to the hard disk, how do I go about calculating the following values for for each I/O model:

1. The number of times, the processor is interrupted?
2. The number of times, the internal memory is
   read by the processor for those 1000 words?
3. The number of times, times the disk
   controller is read by the processor?
4. The number of times the disk
   controller is written to by the processor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the processor word size, the word size on the disk's bus, what kind of metadata needs to be processed in the interrupt, what kind of processor cache is in use, ... With zero information about the platform, nothing can be said.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give an example, on how to solve it (by picking a random processor etc)?

Comment: Why don't you pick a random processor, and supply the missing information? In the presence of  processor caches, the amount of memory accesses can not really be predicted anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In programmed I/O: there will be no interrupts but 1000 read commands and 1000 write commands.

In interrupt driven I/O: there will be 1000 interrupts, 1000 read commands and 1000 write commands.

In DMA: there will be only one interrupt, 1 read command and 1 write command for the transfer of whole block of memory